# Error Message with Change color input in Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I get the message error but I want also red border in input using $.post() by accessing function data. I get the message by using condition data assign to "Empty Field"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loginButton").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var formLogin = $("#formTwo").serialize();

        $.post("loginAction.php", formLogin, function(data){

            if(data === "Empty Field"){
                $("#messageLogin").show("slow", function(){
                    $("#errorLogin").text(data);
                });
            }
            $("#closeTwo").click(function(){
                $("#messageLogin").fadeOut("slow");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

this is my form

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="loginUsername" placeholder="Username" required="required">

    <input type="submit" id="loginButton" value="Login">
</form>
```

and style

```
.errorColor{
    border-color: red;
}
```

loginAction.php

```
<?php>
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $changeColor = FALSE;

    if(empty($name)){
        echo "Empty Field";
        $changeColor = TRUE
    }
    <?
        <script>
            var changeColor = "<?php echo $changeColor;?>;";

            if(changeColor == TRUE){
                $("#loginUsername").addClass("errorColor");
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code

---

`Script`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loginButton").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var formLogin = $("#formTwo").serialize();

        $.post("loginAction.php", formLogin, function(data){
            if(data === "Empty Field"){
                $("#messageLogin").show("slow", function(){
                    $("#errorLogin").text(data);
                    $("#loginUsername").addClass("errorColor");
                });
            }
            $("#closeTwo").click(function(){
                $("#messageLogin").fadeOut("slow");
                $("#loginUsername").removeClass("errorColor");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

---

`Form`

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="loginUsername" placeholder="Username" required="required">
    <input type="submit" id="loginButton" value="Login">
</form>
```

---

`Style`

```
.errorColor {
    border-color: red;
}
```

---

`loginAction.php`

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST["username"];

    if(empty($name)) {
        echo "Empty Field";
    } else {
    /*Process your form*/
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

- from your html code `$_POST["name"]` needs to be `$_POST["username"]` ..
- echo out string in php then check it in the ajax callback

in php

```
<?php
  $name = $_POST["username"];
  $changeColor = 'FALSE';
  if(empty($name)){
    $changeColor = 'TRUE';
  }
  echo $changeColor;
 <?
```

and on js callback

```
$.post("loginAction.php", formLogin, function(data){
  var data = data.trim();
  if(data == "FALSE"){
      // Not Error
  }
  if(data == "TRUE"){
     // Error
  }
});
```